Tracking 'byte': ambiguous symbol
'byte': ambiguous symbol [duplicate]
From another questions about this error, I understand how it appears, but I do not understand how to track its origin.
I am not using byte itself, and I am trying to build a huge open source project. The error info is crazily unhelpful, as it just shows where the byte is re-defined (e.g. rpcdr.h and friends), but not through which path this file is included in the project.
I have also seen questions about it and answers suggesting removing using std, which is sadly not always possible, as big external tools I am using are absolutely full of this (yes, Eigen, I am looking at you).
I also tried to add this at the top level's CMakeLists, but it seems to have no effect:
if (MSVC)
    add_definitions(-D_HAS_STD_BYTE=0)
endif()

So:

Is there some way to easily TRACK through which path of crazy includes does the respective header with redefinition gets to the project? I am coming from Python background where tracking imports is a pretty simple task. Is there sth like this in C++?
Do I just put D_HAS_STD_BYTE to a wrong place? Should it be in all subfolders CMakeLists instead of just in top-level? Or something like this?

Somehow I was able to compile this before I moved some functions to a different file, which I do not really see how could influence the build.

MSVC compiler? With /P flag you can obtain whole preprocessed file  as output and sick regex on it to find. Also it sounds like project was relying on #pragma once but for a different compiler, header guards could fail. This might be problem with that someone used name byte as a nested type name or variable, or dosmething, not that they were referring to std::byte.

It should just be a case of removing using namespace std from the cpp file that's not compiling, if there's using namespace std in your headers then you'll run into more problems in the near future

Note that the #pragma once in MSVC's CL.EXE does not have the same behavior as the #pragma once in GNU's g++ or LLVM's clang++.  (Which is what can happen, since #pragma are non-standard — so they don't have a standard defined behavior.)

You could also share a link to the huge open source project

MSVC has /showIncludes option which shows precisely the chain by which a header got included.

@AlanBirtles as I mentioned in the original post, I am not using it, but my dependencies are. I cannot really rewrite whole Eigen to get rid of using namespace std there.

@IgorTandetnik this is exactly what I was looking for. If you post it as answer, I'll accept.

So is it eigen that's causing the problem? If so a bug report to them would probably help you more than a vague stack overflow question

@AlanBirtles I am not 100% sure but I see them using using namespace std in a lot of code so that was my guess, as I import Eigen pretty much everywhere.

Unless it's in a header file that shouldn't matter (if it is I'd be surprised that such a major library is following very bad practice). Which file are you compiling when you see the error? What's the full text of the compiler output?

@AlanBirtles that is the full error message. That is why I was looking for some way how to get include chain, because I have no idea what is exactly the file that is causing the issue, can be also from some other dependency. Now that I know about /showIncludes, I can try to find that out.

Pretty sure it's not the full message, did you check the compiler output window?
